# Stacking label boxes in ArcMap label expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, labeling

[image: fieldnameExample]

Is there a way to automate getting a seperate text box for two different field names in the label expression in Arcmap?
Right now I have both fieldnames stacked in the same box. Without having to convert to annotation I would like to be able to have each field name in its own box.

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be to duplicate the layer and set the symbology to invisible on one. One would have the one label and the other would have the other label. You'd likely have to work with placement properties to avoid overlapping.

Comment: Adding to jbchurchill's comment about using duplicate layers, you can force the placement of one label to the northeast, and force the placement of the other to the southeast, and you'd get the stacked effect.

Comment: Well that is a good work around but not really what I am looking for. I was really looking for some code or maybe an option in the labeling. This is for a small amount of data and I dont mind converting to graphics and editing the boxes. I was just trying to take out the guess work of knowing the fieldname information for other users not very familiar with arc.

Comment: If you want two labels then label the layer twice, once with 'EXAMPLE FIELDNAME1" and again with "EXAMPLE FIELDNAME2" . In your layers' label options select the method: Define...differently then create a new class (default with one field, new class with the other) with no SQL query and hey, presto, two labels on each feature... getting them to stack is a totally different matter, I don't think there is any option to align labels to other labels.

Comment: i did not think about using the symbols classes. thats a great idea. ill try that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would comment, but it's not letting me. You should check into the Maplex Label Engine, it's very customizable and might have the solution you are looking for.

Comment: I have. Could not find the right options for this particular setup.